# How to calculate MTD given daily account balance in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with columns `[accountid]`, `[DateEnding]`, and `[AccountBalance]`. 
I need to calculate MTD using the balance of the current month and subtracting the account balance from the last day of the previous month for each `accountid`.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT [accountid]
      ,[DateEnding]
      ,[AccountBalance]
     ,[AccountBalance MTD Last] = AccountBalance - FIRST_VALUE(AccountBalance) OVER (PARTITION BY accountid, YEAR(DATEADD(mm,-1,[DateEnding])), MONTH(DATEADD(mm,-1,[DateEnding])) ORDER BY [DateEnding] DESC)
FROM [test]
ORDER BY accountid, DateEnding;
```

Comment: And DDL. Having us guess data types doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here, for each distinct account, we find the latest record available according to DateEnding 
we then find the last day of the last month by taking a number of days away equal to the current day number.  e.g 23rd April 2019 we subtract 23 days to get 1st March  2019
we can then find the balance on that day.

Then put the calculation together in the SELECT

```
SELECT Q1.accountid, 
       Q2.DateEnding , 
       Q3.EOMbalance, 
       Q2.LatestBalance, 
       Q2.LatestBalance - Q3.EOMbalance EOM
      FROM (
                SELECT Distinct t1.accountid FROM test t1
           ) Q1
        CROSS APPLY (
                        SELECT TOP 1 t2.AccountBalance LatestBalance, t2.[DateEnding] 
                            FROM test t2 
                            WHERE t2.[accountid] = Q1.accountid 
                            ORDER BY t2.[DateEnding] DESC
                    ) Q2
        CROSS APPLY (
                        SELECT Top 1 t3.AccountBalance EOMbalance 
                            FROM test t3 
                            WHERE t3.[accountid] = Q1.accountid 
                                AND t3.[DateEnding] 
                                      = dateadd(day,0 - DAY(q2.dateending), q2.dateending)
                            ORDER BY t3.[DateEnding] DESC
                    ) Q3
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer seems a little complicated for this problem (Cross Apply isn't necessary here).

The following may be easier for you:
I first look at the current day's account balances in subquery 'a'.
Then I look at the account balances from the last day of last month's data, in subquery 'b'.

Then it's just a matter of subtracting the two to show the MTD delta:

```
select a.accountid, 
       a.DateEnding, 
       a.AccountBalance as [Current AccountBalance], 
       b.AccountBalance as [EOM prior AccountBalance], --added for clarity
       a.AccountBalance-b.AccountBalance as [AccountBalance MTD Last]
from
    (select accountid, DateEnding, AccountBalance
    from #test 
    where DateEnding = cast(getdate() as date) 
       /* getdate() returns today's date, so this query will also be with respect to today */
    ) a
left join
    (select *
    from #test 
    where DateEnding = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) 
       /*this returns the last day of last month, always*/
    ) b
    on a.accountid = b.accountid
```

Here is the SQL that makes this sample data and #test table.  Simply execute it to have your own '#test' table to run against:

```
/*drop table #test
  drop table #dates */
create table #test ([accountid] varchar(255),[DateEnding] date, [AccountBalance] decimal(16,2))
create table #dates (rnk int,dt date)

insert into #dates (dt)
values (cast('20180101' as date))

DECLARE
  @basedate DATE,
  @d   INT
SELECT
  @basedate = '20180101',
  @d = 1

WHILE @d < (select datediff(day,cast('20180101' as date),getdate())+2)  --select datediff(day,getdate(),cast('20180101' as datetime))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #dates (dt)
    values (DATEADD(day, 1, (select max(dt) from #dates)))
  set @d = @d+1
END

update a 
set a.rnk = b.rnk
from #dates a
left join (select rank() over (order by dt) rnk,dt from #dates) b on a.dt = b.dt

declare @a int
set @a = 1
declare @i int
set @i = 1
while @a <20
begin
    while @i < (select max(rnk) from #dates)
    begin
        insert into #test
        values (@a,(select dt from #dates where rnk = @i),cast(rand()*1000.0+@i as decimal(16,2)))
        set @i=@i+1
    end
    set @a=@a+1
    set @i = 1
end
```

Comment: When I run this code, it doesn't return any results. The test table I made starts from 2018-01-02 and ends 2019-01-02 while the account balance increments by 1. Sample table is:                                                                                                     
1001 0.01   2018-01-02, 
1001 0.02   2018-01-03,
1001 0.03   2018-01-04,
1001 0.04   2018-01-05,
1001 0.05   2018-01-06,
1001 0.06   2018-01-07

Comment: Is there a specific reason to avoid [`EoMonth()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? It has been available since SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @HABO, I wasn't aware of it!

Comment: @SarahFatani; what are the datatypes of your 3 columns in the test table?  I also made test data (adding that to the answer now) and my query returns a result.

Comment: So the code i used to create the test table is: `CREATE TABLE [Ivue].[dbo].[test](
 [accountid] varchar(10),
 [AccountBalance] decimal(15,2) NULL,
 [DateEnding] date NOT NULL)
GO

declare @i as int
set @i=0
DECLARE @balance decimal(15,2) = 0.00
DECLARE @date date = '2018-1-1'
while @i<=365
begin
insert into test values ('1001',@balance + .01,DATEADD(d,1,@date))
SET @balance = @balance + .01
SET @date = DATEADD(d,1,@date)
SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT * FROM [test]`

Comment: The reason your test table doesn't return anything is because my code uses 'getdate' which is always today' date.  Your data stops on 2019/01/02.  If you remake your test table and change 365 to 400, it will work.  However, the important thing here is simply comparing one date in your first subquery, with the date from end of last month.  These should be dynamic for your purposes.